# Google play console does not reduce app download size

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, apk

I'm developing an Android app using Xamarin latest version and Visual Studio latest version aiming Android SDK 8.0.  The app is in Beta track (no release yet).  I've been publishing updates of my app for 2 months using Google Play console, but something weird happened on my last update, because download size of my app growed from 14.16 MB to 29.80 MB and I haven't done anything different in my last update.

My app apk has always been 28 - 29 MB on disk (.apk size) and download size 14 MB aprox.  In my last update I haven't done anything particulary big, just changed code logic and added 4 new resources (pngs total size: 43KB), no new dlls o references, no new componentes. If I use Android Studio apk analyzer on my last apk update, it says my download size should be 13,4 MB, but it seems that Google Play console does not want to reduce download size any more.

[Android Studio shows download size should be 13,4 MB, but download size is actually 29 MB:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0TWc.jpg)

Pls your help.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it was updated, how can I verfy that??, before I built the last app update, I updated Visual Studio from version 15.7.1 to 15.7.3, maybe that could cause the Mono runtime sahred library updated??

Comment: Download size is compressed, where else apk size is uncompressed.

Answer (score 1):

> I updated Visual Studio from version 15.7.1 to 15.7.3

Visual Studio `15.7.1` to `15.7.3` = Xamarin.Android `8.3.0.19` to `8.3.3.2`, consult [releases.xamarin.com](http://releases.xamarin.com) for details.

So the Mono runtime shared library got updated, thus the basically the whole apk is being downloaded again.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  Few hours ago I published another update using same VS 15.7.3, solving bugs with only few lines of code changed, but the size of this new update download is still 29.80 MB. Will the app download never decrease from 29 MB again??.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. r u able to fix this? For me also, till last month our APK size was 40 MB and after upload on play store, download size was 22 MB. But from this month, with same code, i generated APK with 40 MB size, and uploaded on play store. But now download size is still 40 MB it is not getting reduced to 22 MB as it used to reduce earlier. pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Linking your app on release ?

Xamarin.Android applications use a linker to reduce the size of the application. The linker employes static analysis of your application to determine which assemblies are actually used, which types are actually used, and which members are actually used.

Used correctly it can cut your app size in half.(I normally only do this for release builds)

You can get more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker)

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have already use linker and it reduces the size of my apk, but this was BEFORE Google Play increased the size of my apk.  Nevertheless, from June until September I just lived with over-sized apk download size, but in October (just a few days ago) I published a new update, I haven't done any configuration changes in my app, just chages of code in some functions, but for any reason Google Play reduced my apk download size to 12 MB again!!!...I'm happy now, but I would be happier if I can get a reason of why my apk just increases and reduces in size...weird....I hope it wont grow again.